# Specifying sets of environmental variables?

Tags: travis-ci

According to the manual at [travis-ci](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Multiple-Variables-per-Item), if I have in my .travis.yml

```
env:
  - FOO=foo BAR=bar
  - FOO=bar BAR=foo
```

it will trigger two parallel builds:

> 1. FOO=foo and BAR=bar
> 2. FOO=bar and BAR=foo

Is it possible to have conditional code which only run in one instance, i.e. the first? I have a test which I only want to do for the instance (1) but not two, as it will produce an error in (2)?

My .tavis.yml looks at the moment like this:

```
Language: objective-c
before_install:
  - brew update
install:
  - brew tap rkrug/experimental
  - brew tap homebrew/science
  - brew update
env:
  - PACKAGE=nc_spm_08_grass7 INSTALLOPTIONS=""
  - PACKAGE=grass-71         INSTALLOPTIONS="--HEAD"        
script:
#  - brew audit $PACKAGE
  - brew install $INSTALLOPTIONS $PACKAGE
  - brew test -v $PACKAGE
  - brew uninstall $PACKAGE
```

and the `brew audit $PACKAGE` I only want to execute for the first instance.

Comment: Can you give us more details about the language and test framework you are using?

Comment: I have added the ```.travis.yml``` file to the question.

Answer (score -1):

How about using an `if` condition in Bash to test the `$PACKAGE` environment variable?

You could replace the commented line in your `.travis.yml` file with something like:

```
- if [[ "$PACKAGE" == "nc_spm_08_grass7" ]]; then brew audit $PACKAGE; else echo "[SKIPPED] brew audit $PACKAGE"; fi
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot - I thought that there would a more generic way in travis-ci, similar to the way a environmental variable matrix is defined. If not, your answer is perfect for my needs.